# Locked out of phone with airplane mode left on

Tags: wi-fi, security, locked-out, airplane-mode

My son has locked himself out of his phone while on vacation with airplane mode on. Now we can not get back into his phone as its not connecting to internet to change the password from a computer. How can we get back in the phone as we can not turn airplane mode off without the phone being unlocked. We do not really want to do a hard reset.

Comment: If possible, can you add the make and model of your phone so users here can be more helpful in their answers?

Also, can you be more specific in your definition of "locked out"? Did an incorrect passcode get entered too many times? Did the passcode get changed to something now unknown?

My phone allows me to access quick settings, which for me includes airplane mode, without unlocking the device by pulling down the notification shade on the lock screen. Are you able to do something similar on your son's phone?

Comment: Usually you should be able to enable Wifi without unlocking the phone. Only on old devices with Full Disk Encryption this is not possible as Android not fully boots until the correct PIN/password has been entered.

Comment: What is the phone's model and os? Some OS (ex. xiaomi) offer turning on/off of plane mode by long pressing power key

Comment: Thanks for the info, I believe his phone is a Samsung A10, I am unsure which OS it currently has. When I swipe down to access the wifi or airplane mode and tap one of these it asks for password which we are unsure of at this time. And correct he had changed his password while in airplane mode I believe and forgot the password so now we are locked out of it. Currently it has a 4minute timer between password entries.